# facebook developer app permissions settings not applied

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, permissions

I'm using the JavaScript SDK to embed FB login to my web app.

I've set my app permissions in the developer console to require the user share their email address with me, but the login window that pops up does not reflect that... instead it keeps saying to the user on initial login:

"(app name) will receive the following info: your public profile and friend list."

...wheras it should say "email" as well. I've tried adding a myriad of other "extended permissions" as a test, but those do not show up as well.

I've tried deleting the FB app and creating a new one so that there's no caching... and I've waited "days" between requests to make sure that things have propagated to all of the FB servers (they say it may take "several minutes").

Am I doing something wrong? Does the Javascript SDK login need a special setting to pull the correct permissions list?

Anyone else running into this?

================

## ANSWERED / UPDATED

Figured it out.

I'd already had the "email scope" in the FB.api call:

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me?scope=email', function(response) {
console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
});
```

...but what was missing was "scope" in the button itself... if you don't do that, then it doesn't work.

The Working Login Button, in my case:

```
<fb:login-button size="medium" show-faces="false" scope="email" onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and put some of code? specially when you call the dialog permissions

Comment: This has been discussed here multiple times before … the permissions you set in the app dashboard are _only_ for logins triggered by accessing the app from the app center – as it also _explicitly_ says there: _“Use these settings to enter the set of permissions your app requires __when displayed in App Center__”_ – in every other scenario, where you trigger login yourself, you have to use the `scope` parameter as described in the documentation.

Comment: Figured it out.

I'd already had the "email scope" in the FB.api call:

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?scope=email', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });

...but what was missing was "scope" in the button itself... if you don't do that, then it doesn't work.

The Working Login Button, in my case:

<fb:login-button size="medium" show-faces="false" scope="email" onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Facebook
</fb:login-button>